# How to use Django's DurationField with Postgres, when defined previously using sqlite?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, psycopg2

I recently moved all my data from `sqlite` to `postgres`. All fields seem to work fine except for the `duration` field. It is shown as an integer in the admin panel and it does not let me edit or save.

It works fine with sqlite. However after moving to Postgres, I get the following errors (upon saving or updating):

> ProgrammingError at /admin/content/movie/add/

> column "duration" is of type bigint but expression is of type interval

> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    """
    Stores movie related information.
    """
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name', max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='slug', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='description', blank=True)
    poster = models.ImageField(verbose_name='poster',upload_to='posters/movies', default='defaults/video.webp', validators=[validate_image])
    # Field of interest
    duration = models.DurationField(verbose_name='duration')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='created_at', auto_now_add=True)
```

I also used the following `length` method for successfully converting the field to human readable form (when using sqlite), but it does not work after moving to postgres. It says:

> duration (int) does not have 'days' attribute

```py
def length(self):
        """
        Converts timedelta into hours and minutes.
        """
        days, seconds = self.duration.days, self.duration.seconds
        hours = days * 24 + seconds // 3600
        minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
        seconds = (seconds % 60)

        if hours == 0:
            length = f'{minutes} min'
        else:
            if minutes == 0:
                length = f'{hours} h'
            else:
                length = f'{hours} h {minutes} min'
        return length
```

> Note: I used `pgloader` to load the sqlite data. https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#migrating-from-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield):

> A field for storing periods of time - modeled in Python by timedelta. When used on PostgreSQL, the data type used is an interval and on Oracle the data type is INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(6). Otherwise a bigint of microseconds is used.

So you either need to make the field in the model an `IntegerField` to match the the data or change the data to a Postgres `interval`. Since in SQLite the data is stored as microseconds then something like:

```
select (1000000::text || ' microseconds')::interval;
 interval 
----------
 00:00:01
```

Comment: I tried both approaches mentioned. I finally changed my data to Postgres interval. However very large integers seem to not be supported. Converting microseconds to milliseconds could be an option.